# ProgressDialog always indeterminate, even when setting style initially to STYLE_HORIZONTAL

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Yes, I realize ProgressDialogs are deprecated and ugly, but that's not something I can change right now. Please help!

```
m_ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());             
m_ProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL); 
m_ProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);              
m_ProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
m_ProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
m_ProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
m_ProgressDialog.setOwnerActivity(getActivity());
m_ProgressDialog.show();
```

The dialog is shown fine, but no matter what I change, the dialog is always indeterminate. Apparently the ProgressBar retrieved in the onCreate method of ProgressDialog has `mIndeterminate = true` and `mOnlyIndeterminate = true` despite these being false by default, which doesn't allow setIndeterminate to do anything. What do I do?

Comment: This code shows a **Determinate** `ProgressDialog` on a Pixel running Android O. Please add a little more information and context.

Comment: I can't add too much since this is work code, but this is all contained with in one synchronized method, and I intend to have a determinate progressdialog, but it isn't. Calling show() triggers the onCreate of the progressdialog, which retrieves the progressbar from some layout file, and this progressbar is set to always be indeterminate. I'm on API 28, so that might be messing it up, I'll try running this code in a different app and get back to you.